# How to get file size in Dynamics AX / X++?

Tags: axapta, dynamics-ax-2009

Does exists some Axapta method to get the size of a file ?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use WinAPI function GetFileSize;

```
client public static int getFileSize(int hFile)
```

Example usage code is here;

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa609747(v=ax.50).aspx

References;

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa586314(v=ax.10).aspx

Answer (score 0):

You can use the System.IO namespace too.  For whatever reason, I don't have the getFileSize() in my AX instance available.

```
server static void main(Args args)
{
    System.IO.FileInfo  fi;
    int64               length;
    ;

    fi = new System.IO.FileInfo(@'C:\temp.csv');
    length = fi.get_Length();
    info(strfmt("%1", int642str(fi.get_Length())));
}
```